# Hololens remote supply and video, audio live streaming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

We are currently developing a Hololens remote support module using LowLatencyMRVC. I would like to know if there is a setting or option to receive a voice when receiving Hololens video from LowLatencyMRVC. Then, the audio data is recorded for one second using a socket and made into a wav file, and the created file is sent to the client through the server to reproduce the wav file received by the client. However, when the voice data reception and LowLatencyMRVC are combined, the load of the program in Hololens is increased, and the program is terminated. Are there any suggestions on how to solve the problem or voice communication?

Comment: if you include the code you're using chances are you'll get a better answer.